# Obj-c show navbar after hideBarOnSwipe true

Tags: objective-c

Currently the navbar will hide if the user is scrolling down. But it won't display back the navbar when user is scrolling up. how to display the navbar back when the user is scrolling up?

i am using this code to hide the navbar

```
self.navigationController.hidesBarsOnSwipe = YES;
```

The navbar will display back if the user tap twice on the top screen area, but I found it won't be so user-friendly.

Have been searching for the answers for quite a while, but can't find any 
 clue. What am I missing??

thanks!

Comment: I don't have any problem. See this [gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3og0IEg9LzMiBnCg2A/giphy.gif). Have you used auto layout?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try adding scrollViewScroll as below

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    CGPoint scrollOffset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    if (scrollOffset.y >= 40)
    {
        if (![self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
        {
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self.navigationController isNavigationBarHidden])
        {
            [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used one Git lib for scroll table view/ Scroll top to bottom / bottom to top. It will automatically adjust the Navigation bar.
[AMScrollingNavbar](https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar)

you can use like this.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [(ScrollingNavigationController *)self.navigationController followScrollView:self.tableView delay:40.0f];
}
```